# jQuery Uploadify plugin with HTTPS

Tags: jquery, flash, https, uploadify

jQuery Uploadify plugin uses flash swf to upload files. I have implemented it on a HTTP website but now I want to do the same on HTTPS. It works fine on IE but breaks in FF by returning IO error. It must be flash security issue.

Is there any work around to get the flash working over SSL. Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I was using a self-signed certificate to test my uploadify with https, surely it didnt work.

Then I tried the same with CA certificate from a third party and it does work partially. I implemented Uploadify with ASP .Net with IIS 7. First time upload always fail [either first for the day or may be session, not sure which one] with http 500, due an IO at BEGIN_REQUEST on IIS 7, but, subsequent uploads work smoothly.

This issue may be specific to IIS 7 and it may work with other web servers [Its not confirmed, as I didn't try on another].

BTW due time crunch I replaced uploadify with a similar silverlight project from codeplex. Just search for 'silverlight multi file upload' on codeplex, just in case if that helps.

Comment: At least for me, the self-signed cert failed but real certificate worked (at least so far).

Answer (score 0):

I use the Uploadify plugin (v2.0.3) with HTTPS and it works fine for me.  Make sure all your resources (css, js, flash) are loaded from https.  Where does the error come from? Does everything load properly?  If you give a little more info maybe I can help debug.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did add Uploadify 2.0.2 on the my test server with HTTPs and IIS 7, it seems to give problem when I upload for the first time each day.
Just in case if you have experience implementing Uploadify with ASP .NET & IIS 7, a little help would help.
BTW I replaced uploadify with Silverlight project from codeplex & its working real smooth.

Comment: I havne't tried it with IIS so that might be the issue.  Glad you found another solution!

Comment: I am having trouble using Uploadify v2.1.0 with HTTPS. I have already set all the absolute paths to https:// the rest are in relative path. What information do I need to supply so you can help?